# Routing Error uninitialized constant rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error.When I want to run te server on localhost:3000/api/v1/songs.json
Routing Error
uninitialized constant API::V1::SongsController.
Thats my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    namespace :api do 
        namespace :v1 do 
            resources :songs, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy]
        end
    end  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

```
Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url      
Path Match
api_v1_songs_path   GET /api/v1/songs(.:format) 
api/v1/songs#index

POST    /api/v1/songs(.:format) 
api/v1/songs#create

api_v1_song_path    PATCH   /api/v1/songs/:id(.:format) 
api/v1/songs#update

PUT /api/v1/songs/:id(.:format) 
api/v1/songs#update

DELETE  /api/v1/songs/:id(.:format) 
api/v1/songs#destroy
```

and thats my SongsController:

```
class Api::V1::SongsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def index
    respond_with Song.all
  end

  def create
    respond_with :api, :v1, Song.create(song_params)
  end

  def destroy
    respond_with Song.destroy(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    song = Song.find(params["id"])
    song.update_attributes(song_params)
    respond_with song, json: song
  end

  private

  def song_params
    params.require(:song).permit(:id, :name, :singer_name, :genre, :updated_at, :tag)
  end
end
```

Comment: You probably don't have your `SongsController` namespaced properly, just as the error message says.

Comment: Can I know your directory structure for controller, as I think it must be in app/controllers/api/v1/songs_controller.rb

Comment: I have SongsController like this above

Comment: change your `namespace :v1` into `namespace :V1`

Comment: right now I'm getting this error;

Comment: Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/songs.json"

Rails.root: /home/huseyin/item/item_cart

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

You don't have any routes defined!

Please add some routes in config/routes.rb.

Comment: Which Rails version is this? because we run a similar setup and this works out of the box for us.

Comment: that's my rails version: Rails 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to copy how we have this running, cause I cannot see a direct difference between your code and our code....

**routes.rb**

```
constraints subdomain: Settings.subdomains.api do  # you can ignore this
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :maps, only: [] do
        collection do
          get :world_map
        end
     end
   end
 end
```

**maps_controller.rb**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class MapsController < BaseController
      def world_map; end
    end
  end
end
```

**routes output**

```
world_map_api_v1_maps GET     /v1/maps/world_map(.:format)  api/v1/maps#world_map {:subdomain=>"api"}
```

The spelling is really crucial from what I can see.
The directort structure for us:

`app/controllers/api/v1/maps_controller.rb`

So check those points and this should work because it's standard Rails magic.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working as well I could'nt understand what my problem is ?

Comment: last guess, write your controller the way I did, defining the modules, and not inline....